# ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, ros, robot

I want to use tensorflow model in ROS.and this code can work,however,it is very slow because of everytime it restore the model

```
class image_converter:
def __init__(self):
    self.demo_pub = rospy.Publisher(
        "/demo/pic", Image, queue_size=1)
    # todo pub distance and angle data
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
        "/camera/live_view", Image, self.callback)
def callback(self, data):
    self.callback_once(data)
def callback_once(self, data):
    # imgmsg_to_cv2
    try:
        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
    img1 = cv_image
    data,_,img=read_img(img1)
        #print(data)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model4/model.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model4/'))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
        feed_dict = {x:data}
        logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name('logits_eval:0')
        classification_result = sess.run(logits,feed_dict)
        index=(tf.argmax(classification_result,1).eval())
```

so i change this code like this :

```
class image_converter:
def __init__(self):
    self.sess=tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model4/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(self.sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model4/'))
    self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    self.x = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    self.demo_pub = rospy.Publisher(
        "/demo/pic", Image, queue_size=1)
    # todo pub distance and angle data
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(
        "/camera/live_view", Image, self.callback)
def callback(self, data):
    try:
        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
    data,_,img=read_img(cv_image)
    feed_dict = {self.x:data}
    logits = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('logits_eval:0')
    classification_result = self.sess.run(logits,feed_dict)
    print(classification_result)
    index=(tf.argmax(classification_result,1).eval(session=self.sess))
```

there is an error occoured :in the last line 
**ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.**

so,what should i do to solve this error.thank you very much.